# handle optimistic locking exception grails - mongodb

Tags: mongodb, grails, e-commerce

i need a help for some really serious issue, so the thing is i have a e commerce site , where single user placing order at a time is working fine, but if more than one user try to order the same product, then i am getting this exception

```
org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.OptimisticLockingException: The instance was updated by another user while you were editing
Point : in.emkart.api.OrderAPIController.save(OrderAPIController.groovy:70)
```

so my my code is like

```
/** some code **/

            if (product && orderContinue) {
                product = updateQuantityForProduct(product)
                order?.product = product
/** some code  **/
              try{ 
              // some code
              product.save() // line 70
              // some code
              }
             catch(Exception e){
              log.debug "unable to place order-->"+e /** exception --> (unable to place order-->org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.OptimisticLockingException: The instance was updated by another user while you were editing
Point : in.emkart.api.OrderAPIController.save(OrderAPIController.groovy:70) ) **/
               }
```

what are the fixes that can help me to prevent this and also is this possible to keep the another user waiting or some kind of queue to maintain so that once previous order is complete then only next request goes on to place order.